# How to make this function work for a username or email as well?

Tags: php, sql, function, authentication

I have the following function that I use to check a user login, at it's state it can only check the username and the password:

```
public function checkUserLogin($username, $password) {
    $password = hash_hmac('sha512', $password, $this->salt($username, $password));
    $sql      = 'SELECT user_username,user_level FROM users WHERE user_username = ? AND user_password = ?';
    // Check Login Attempts
    if (isset($_SESSION['attempts']) && $_SESSION['attempts'] >= NUMBER_OF_ATTEMPTS) {
        $lockdown            = true;
        $message['lockdown'] = true;
        $message['message']  = SYSTEM_LOCKDOWN_MESSAGE;
        return json_encode($message);
    } else {
        if ($stmt = $this->connect->prepare($sql)) {
            $stmt->bind_param('ss', $username, $password);
            $stmt->execute();
            $stmt->bind_result($username, $admin);
            if ($stmt->fetch()) {
                $_SESSION['member_logged_in'] = true;
                $_SESSION['username']         = $username;
                $_SESSION['admin']            = $admin;
                $_SESSION['attempts']         = 0;
                $stmt->close();
                $ip = $this->getIP();
                $sql      = "UPDATE users SET user_last_login_date = NOW(), user_last_login_ip = '$ip' WHERE user_username = '$username'";
                if ($stmt = $this->connect->prepare($sql)) {
                    $stmt->execute();
                    $stmt->close();
                } else {
                    $error              = true;
                    $message['error']   = true;
                    $message['message'] = CANNOT_PREPARE_DATABASE_CONNECTION_MESSAGE;
                    return json_encode($message);
                }

                $error                        = false;
                if($_SESSION['admin']==1){
                    $message['level']             = true;
                }
                $message['error']             = false;
                $message['message']           = SUCCESFUL_LOGIN_MESSAGE;
                return json_encode($message);
            } else {
                @$_SESSION['attempts'] = $_SESSION['attempts'] + 1;
                $error              = true;
                $message['error']   = true;
                $message['message'] = FAILED_LOGIN_MESSAGE;
                return json_encode($message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Making abstraction of all the functions that are included there and other variables, I need to know if I can make this function work for the username as well for the email.

What I mean is, I want to give the user the chance to login either by his / her email or by his / her username. Is that possible to do to my function, and if yes how ?

Comment: Finally, someone who does passwords right! +1 for hashes and parameters

Comment: Note that your usernames are case-sensitive, which many users won't expect.

Comment: Thanks, well there is more to the hash, but that's not relative to my question. What do you mean by username case-sensitive ?

Comment: @SLaks: There's no evidence that the username is case-sensitive. He's probably just using a case-insensitive collation on the column.

Comment: @webbiedave: He's using the username as a salt.  Unless his salt function is case insensitive (which would be strange), the username is case sensitive.

Comment: @Slaks: You are right. The salt.

Comment: In my db, my username is set as ci. The salt, I'm not sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you want `WHERE (user_username = ? OR user_email = ?)`.

You will need to retrieve the salt from the database, though.
Best practice is to use a long sequence of cryptographically secure random bytes as salt, not the username, so you should be doing that anyway.

Comment: This one doesn't work, there's a mysqli error, wrong number of parameters if I insert `WHERE (user_username = ? OR user_email = ?)`.

Comment: @Roland: You need to add an email parameter.  (and beware the salt)

Comment: I managed to make it work now, I had to modify the salt algorithm for that, but it works now. Thanks for the tip :)

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you could modify the query to check $username against both the username AND email fields in the database, e.g. something like

```
SELECT user_username,user_level
FROM users
WHERE (? IN (user_username, user_email)) AND user_password = ?';
```

Answer (score 0):

Check for the existence of `@` and change your query accordingly:

```
if (strpos($username, '@') === false) {
    $nameField = 'user_username';
} else {
    $nameField = 'user_email';
}

$sql = 'SELECT user_username,user_level FROM users WHERE '.$nameField.' = ? AND user_password = ?';
```

The other issue is the salt being based on the username. This will obviously fail if the user decides to switch to the email address. As [has been suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9022052/#answer-9022078), use a separate salt (unrelated to the username) and add an extra query upfront to retrieve it.

Answer (score -2):

```
$query = "
    SELECT
        `user_username`,
        `user_level`
    FROM
        `users`
    WHERE 
    (
            `users`.`user_username` = '".mysql_real_escape_string($user)."'
        AND
            `users`.`user_password` = '".mysql_real_escape_string($pass)."'
    )
    OR (
            `users`.`user_email` = '".mysql_real_escape_string($user)."'
        AND
            `users`.`user_password` = '".mysql_real_escape_string($pass)."'
    )
";
```

Just make the query like this. I'd advice using the mysql_real_escape_string as it makes your code better protected against SQL-injection (read-up on that!).

From this point on, you can continue with your code.

Comment: Is that a good idea ? Using `mysql_real_escape_string()`, because I use mysqli.

Comment: @Roland: You're correct; this is a bad idea.  He's also storing passwords in plain text, which is a worse idea.  And the boolean logic is overly complicated.

Comment: I'm storing hashes, not the actual pass. And I'm not storing the salt with which I'm hashing the pass.

Comment: Dudes, the logic before and after is PHP. I was just referring to the question: "How to make this function work for a username or email as well?" Not the rest, though I agree with you guys. 

Yes, I think could've answered with a less extensive query - like you guys did. However, in my opinion such a basic question (no offence Roland) shouldn't be answered with short SQL. That stuff you'll learn as you go - again, in my opnion. 

PS: I was first when I started typing :)